# Rewrite everything with the new domain name (including subdomains)

Tags: rewrite

I want simple to rewrite everthing from OLD.COM to NEW.COM including subdomains and stuff - whatever user types in should just be replaced with NEW.COM and the rest of it stays as is. 
I tried this but it's not working for subdomains.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?[^\.]+)\.old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What did I miss?
Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the subdomains in the apache config and replace it with this:

```
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ #Wherever your site is located now
    ServerName olddomain.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)olddomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

That should redirect all subdomains.

Comment: I tried it and this error comes up: "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: Sorry, had a \ that wasn't supposed to be there. Does it work now?

Comment: still nothing happens if "WWW" is missing or by entering subdomains  ( http://olddomain.com + http://subdomains.olddomain.com )

Comment: Made some changes. Please try again.

Comment: only thing left is that subdomains aren't working are (like "http://anysubdomain.olddomain.com") - is it a server-based problem or can it be solved via .htaccess?

Comment: Where did you put the lines above?

Comment: I put the .htaccess in the root on my server. This is the complete code: `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Aaah :-). You should put them in the general config-file for your old domain. Or create a catch-all if you don't have one. `<VirtualHost *:80>` You can only do this with a .htaccess file if you copy it to every subdomain.

Comment: btw: is there a chance to do it with Javascript if I put it into the index file or root?

Comment: No, The easiest method is to copy the same .htaccess file to every subdomain. The root of you site will not be loaded when you access it via a subdomain. Added some more information.